# Simple Page crashes Browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have a simple list view built using JQuery Mobile.
It works fine on the desktop, but when you run it on Safari or Chrome on an iPhone (4S running 6.1), it crashes the browser.

I have put the link up on jsbin - http://jsbin.com/efehip/1

What could it be that causes the crash? There are no errors in the console on Desktop.
I can't see any tags that are incorrectly paired or anything else which should cause this issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's a very long list, it might be too much memory to load (though that sounds weird). You could try to page it so that it only loads a portion of the data. This will probably require server side scripting though.